# Create silence WAVE stream with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

Being new to NAudio and audio applications, I don't know exactly how to implement the following:

I want to make an empty (silence) wave stream and convert it to `WaveChannel32`, in order to feed it to a `MultiplexingWaveProvider` and mute one output channel.
I tried it with a silence wav file and mutes successfully the output channel, but in the end I don't want to use a file in the application, but do it "on the fly".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a silence producing `IWaveProvider` very easily. Create a class that implements `IWaveProvider` and in the `Read` method, always return the number of bytes asked for. Fill the buffer with zeros as well.

Something like this will do for the `Read` method:

```
public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
   for(int n = 0; n < count; n++) buffer[offset++] = 0;
   return count;
}
```

Comment: Thx Mark. This solution is probably what I looking for!

Comment: It looks like Mark overlooked his own NAudio.Wave.SilenceProvider, which already provides exactly this implementation